# How to show that $k[X]\otimes_k k[Y] \cong k[X \times Y]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be affine varieties. How to show that $k[X]\otimes_k k[Y] \cong k[X \times Y]$? I think that we can define a map $\varphi: k[X]\otimes_k k[Y] \to k[X \times Y] $ by $\varphi(\sum_i f_i \otimes g_i) = \sum_i f_i(x)g_i(y)$. But how could we show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism? If we are given a regular function $h: X \times Y \to k$, could we write $h$ in the form $h=\sum_i f_i(x)g_i(y)$? If $\sum_i f_i(x)g_i(y)=0$, could we conclude that $\sum_i f_i\otimes g_i=0$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Google "stackexchange coordinate ring of product", the question has been asked here $\approx 10$ times.